# How to append host name to a single text file from different servers in lan

Tags: shell

I am installing a app by running a script on number of servers (say 10), at the end I need to get a list of servers that the secript run in a single file.
Ex:

```
Server-1
Server-2
Server-3.....Server-10
```

I tried with this, but it is creating agent_name_list.txt on local box with only that hostname.

Any Idea how can I get a consolidated list of servers that agent installed by script in one place?

```
agent_name='hostname'
nslookup $agent_name | grep Name | awk '{print $2}' >  /var/tmp/$agent_name_list.txt
```

Comment: put code on { code sample }

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me the exact output you're trying to achieve, but I see 2 fixes that you'll need to make to your code:

```
agent_name=$(hostname)
nslookup $agent_name | grep Name | awk '{print $2}' >  /var/tmp/${agent_name}_list.txt
```

This can be reduced further to

```
agent_name=$(hostname)
nslookup $agent_name | awk '/Name/{print $2}' >  /var/tmp/${agent_name}_list.txt
```

One of awk's many features is to match patterns, and limit it's action to just the lines matched.

---

**Comments**

```
agent_name='hostname'
```

Here you're just setting the value of agent_name to the string value "hostname"
Note how above, I'm using the shell command substitution feature to capture the current value of the `hostname` command.

```
nslookup $agent_name | grep Name | awk '{print $2}' >  /var/tmp/$agent_name_list.txt
```

And here, you need to use the variable "wrappers" `{}` so that the shell doesn't try to evaluate $agent_name_list as a variable. Because you've assigned a value to agent_name, there is not value for agent_name_list. Asumming a leading '$' char, the `{}` wrapper tells the shell "this much is a variable name, whats the value?" ..

If the corrected example above doesn't completely solve your problem, consider editing your message to include sample input data, required output given the sample data, your current code and the output from that current code.

IHTH